# Javascript complicated if statement

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, conditional-statements

Ok so im in a situation with Angularjs/Javascript. I have a list of items from json and they all have sub categories. So what i need to happen is when my list is shown, if the user chooses this item in that list, then everything in the sub category that is related will show.

**Example**

```
Group [
    { Item 1:
        { sub 30,
    },
    Item 2:
        { sub 53,
    },
    Item 7:
        { sub 21,
    },
    Item 2:
        { sub 97,
    },
}]
```

As you can see, there are two "Item 2"'s. If the user chooses Item 2 then sub 53, and 97 will show. I wouldn't know how to execute the condition statement or if there is any way to do this the 'Angular way'

Comment: Your array example is malformed. And you need to show at least what you have tried

Comment: At least fix the data to valid JSON structure.

Comment: @Moogs sorry about the JSON. Just trying to give a quick example.

Comment: If you want a good quality answer, you must provide a good quality question with proper code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var items = [
        {
            "Item 1": "sub 30"
        },
        {
            "Item 2": "sub 53"
        },
        { 
            "Item 7": "sub 21",
        },
        {
            "Item 2": "sub 97"
        }
    ];
    
    var grouped = {};
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        for (var item in items[i]) {
            if (!grouped[item]) {
                grouped[item] = {};
                grouped[item].subs = [];
            }
            grouped[item].subs.push(items[i][item]);
        }
    }
    
    $scope.group = grouped;
    
    $scope.toggleSubs = function(item) {
       $scope.group[item].showSubs = !$scope.group[item].showSubs;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(item, data) in group">
        <a href ng-click="toggleSubs(item)">{{item}}</a>
        <div ng-show="data.showSubs">
            <div ng-repeat="sub in data.subs">
             <ul>
                 <li>{{sub}}</li>
             </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Shouldn't of doubted you.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't angular specific but I would process your data when received and make it easier to have a list of sub values referenced by Item properties.

```
 var newGroup = {
    'Item 1': [30],
    'Item 2': [53, 97],
    'Item 3': [21]
};
```

Then you can use the key value syntax in an ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that user has already selected one of the items and there are many subitems in the list. 
The easiest approach would be to assign a variable as the selected item and its subitem upon 'user selection'

```
 ...// on user selection 
 $scope.selectedItem = 'itemName from user input'; 
 $scope.selected = $array_of_subitems; // this is item2 for example , and contains all the subs belonging to that
```

**NOTE**: if you can provide more specifics how you are calling the selection, i can improve the code above

In your html, since you need to show the selected element, you can do that easily to show all subitems

```
 <h1>Item Named : {{selectedItem}} has following subitems</h1>
 <div ng-repeat="subitem in selected">
      {{subitem}}
 <div>
```